# I select columns A-D but Excel scatter graph only shows column D

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want x axis to be column A which is date & time.
I want columns B, C, and D values each to be different color on y axis.

Here are my steps...

1. open excel
2. Data > From Text
3. Select columns A-D
4. Insert > Scatter chart
   ...only shows column D

HERE IS GRAPH THAT ONLY SHOWS COLUMN D...

[image]

HERE ARE SELECTED COLUMNS A-D........
[image]

Comment: Hi @DougNull - have you tried changing the source data (right click on the chart) - and adding / moving the data around that way?

Comment: "Select Data Source".   I will try

Comment: Excel "auto" graphing from selection is sometimes tripped up by specific formatting in the headers or lack of data (blanks) like in your example. What happens if you only select A and B then plot? That is sometimes easier... select only x column and one y series column, plot and then right click the chart "select source data" and manually add the other series. Another option is to select everything, plot, go to the same dialogue and select ~"switch rows/columns".

Comment: Also make sure the data is actually imported and formatted as numbers and not text. Text to data import is sometimes tripped up by region settings for the decimal seperator (. vs ,). To test make duplicate columns with formula `=A2+0` in G2. Then copy and paste G2 across G2 downto K1000.

Comment: Go to Chart Design- Select Data and check the data as: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UROq9.png

Answer (score 0):

If those "blank" cells aren't really blank (contain space or other non-printing characters), Excel will treat them as text and parse the data differently than you would expect.

Select the plotted series and look at the series formula to see how Excel parsed it. I'll bet it looks something like this:

`=SERIES(Sheet1!$D$1:$D$220,Sheet1!$A$221:$C$500,Sheet1!$D$221:$D$500,1)`

Where the first three columns are used for X values, which doesn't work in an XY chart (though formatted as date-time, the first X value in your chart is zero), and the top at least 218 cells in column D are used as the series name (the chart title is "SELL  433" which are the values in D1 and D218 the first number found in column D, and the red outline that highlights series names surrounds all of the visible part of column D in the first screenshot).

You would expect instead three series like this:

`=SERIES(Sheet1!$B$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$500,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$500,1)`
`=SERIES(Sheet1!$C$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$500,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$500,2)`
`=SERIES(Sheet1!$D$1,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$500,Sheet1!$D$2:$D$500,3)`

To fix this, press Ctrl+G (GoTo), Special Cells, Constants, Text, then press Delete. Now rebuild the chart.

[image: Go To Special]